# Toggle Button Requires 2 Clicks Once Initially Clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a basic toggle button set up, but for some reason it requires two clicks after the initial click to execute the function. Had a look at some of the other answers, but not sure why this is happening:

```
<div>
<button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true"> <span><i class="ion-navicon-round"></i></span> </button>
</div>

<div class="row main-menu"></div>
```

jQuery :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".dropdown-toggle").click(function () {
        $(".main-menu").toggle();
    });
});
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try to avoid `<span> ` tag inside the button tag

Comment: Works fine : https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/23744/

Comment: Hi Zakaria, it works fine in that jsfiddle, but for some reason not in my live preview...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe problem is with hiding menu at start? You use some code for it? Or maybe CSS?

Thi code works well (i added  **$('.main-menu').hide();**)

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  // Hide menu at start
  $('.main-menu').hide();
  $(".dropdown-toggle").click(function () {
    $(".main-menu").toggle();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
<button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true"> <span><i class="ion-navicon-round"></i></span>MENU BUTTON</button>
</div>

<div class="row main-menu"><p>MENU...</p></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all help. Turns out it was due to having data-toggle="dropdown" in the button, which seemed to mess with the execution of the function

Answer (score -1):

If you are using bootstrap than Its work with same of your code, Tried like this. just include bootstrap.js in your code

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
            $(".dropdown-toggle").click(function () {
                $(".main-menu").toggle();
            });
        });
    </script>
    <body>
    <div>
    <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true"> <span><i class="ion-navicon-round"></i></span> </button>
    </div>
    </body>
    <div class="row main-menu">I will be toggle </div>
```

Comment: What is it to do with Bootstrap? It's simple jQuery code, it should toggle the menu on click, regardless of Bootstrap's CSS or JS.